# Get GridView Row Count with Condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio, gridview

I am using VS2005 ASP.NET C# and SQL Server 2005.

I have a GridView on my webpage and a couple of labels.

I am able to allocate the value of the number of rows into a label by the following:

```
UserFound.Text = GridView1.Rows.Count.ToString();
```

However, I would like to allocate another value to another label which counts the number of rows when the value inside column *Role* is equals to *"admin"*.

How can I do it? Examples and sample code will be appreciated.

---

**EDIT:**

```
int admincount=0;
foreach (DataRow oRow in GridView1.Rows)
{
    if (GridView1.Rows["User Role"].ToString().Trim().Contains("Admin"))
    {
        admincount++;
    }
}

AdminFound.Text = admincount.ToString();
```

I am getting the error:

`The best overloaded method match for System.Web.UI.WebContols.GridViewCollection.this[int] has some invalid arguments` and

`Argument '1': canot convert from 'string' to 'int'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run  sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() with a select statement like:

```
select Count(UserRole) where UserRole = 'Admin'
```

The value returned you can then use as your label text;

Answer (score 1):

Well.. 
I assume u use `ADO.Net`

Before `GridView1.DataBind()`, do a `for` loop to Gridview or the datatable which you are going to bind to `Gridview1`

```
int admRows=0;
for(int i=0;i<datatable1.Rows.Count;i++)
{
  if(datatable1.Rows[i]["adminColumn"].ToString().Trim().ToLower().Contains("admin"))
  {
    admRows++;
  }
}
admFound.Text=admRows.ToString();
GridView1.DataSource=datatable1;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

P.S. `datatable1.Rows[i]["adminColumn"]` or `datatable1.Rows["adminColumn"][i]`.. i m not sure.. google it

Comment: It is much easier and more understandable if you use a foreach construct in your loop. For example `foreach (DataRow oRow in datatable1.Rows)`. Then you don't have to worry about the `[i]` syntax.

Comment: Yea, `foreach` is better if the purpose of the loop is only to count. But in future, it is possible that he will need to check whether it is the first row or the last row or some particular row of the table. When that happens, I haven't found a way to achieve that in `foreach`.. So I have to use the `for` loop again. Can anyone tell me to achieve that in `foreach` ?

Comment: If we need to do this, we just add a counter variable outside the loop that is incremented at the end of each pass through the loop.

Comment: Isn't it the same as doing `for` loop??

Comment: No, because you don't have to index into the data table rows for every column that you want to access in the row.

Comment: yea.. u r right abt that.. if I am to argue, I would say that you still have to get the index of `datatable` for conditioning.. But I agree with u.. `foreach` is less dangerous..